# Netbeans 6.8 on Win 7 64 bit very slow (Scala plugin)

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, netbeans6.8

I had a windows vista machine with much lower specs and Netbeans6.8+Scala2.8 worked fine.

old specs: Vista home premium, 4 GB ram, 320 gb hdd 5400 rpm, java 1.6.0.16

new specs: Win 7 professional, 8 GB ram, 250 gb ssd, java 1.6.0.21

The compilation on the new machine is much slower. Java and javaw take up to 95% cpu during compile.

any ideas how this can be fixed?

I am not able to upgrade NB due to some restrictions.

Comment: it seems there is a problem with netbeans config. I have another colleague with 64bit Win 7 (with less RAM), and he has managed to get it to work smoothly. I'll get back after finding out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question since I found the cause:

The reason (don't know if it applies to other Netbeans versions apart from 6.8):

- the new PC runs 64 bit Windows 7 and a 64 bit JDK (I forgot to mention this in my question)
- the old PC rund 32 bit Vista and 32 bit JDK

Netbeans currently runs in 32 bit mode only, so when on the new PC, it was an issue with running the 64 bit JVM from Netbeans. This problem is discussed here:

[Issues with running 64 bit JDK under Netbeans](https://superuser.com/questions/94101/how-to-pin-netbeans-to-windows-7-taskbar/94103#94103)

The easiest solution for me was to install a 32 bit JDK and force Netbeans to use it as the default platform (required modifying netbeans.conf). Additionally, `-J-Xmx512m`
did not work on the 32-bit JDK, so I had to set it to `-J-Xmx400m`

The following stackoverflow link was also helpful in figuring out the optimal settings:

[Netbeans config options for optimal performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217140/java-settings-for-netbeans-6-8-on-osx-10-5-8-to-avoid-100-cpu-usage)

Answer (score 1):

All I can say is try to ask to see if you can get a newer version of Netbeans. Netbeans 6.9.1 has many performance improvements, with Netbeans Dev being faster. You can make an argument saying that the slow performance is impacting your work.

Really the only other things you can do is disable modules you don't need which might free up some resources.

Answer (score 1):

With that much memory you could try to run NB on Vista or Linux in a VirtualBox instance.