# is there a way to make netbeans use the hotspot server vm

Tags: java, netbeans, jvm-hotspot

Does anybody know if netbeans by default uses the hotspot server vm?  I'm trying to figure out if that would be an option of not.
Thanks!

-roger-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [seems to be this option](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic6301.html) to make NetBeans run '`java -server`' instead of just java:

```
netbeans -J-server
```

Note: in term of raw performance though, this might not be the most important option to use.
See [Java Settings for Netbeans 6.8 on OSX 10.5.8 to avoid 100% cpu usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217140/java-settings-for-netbeans-6-8-on-osx-10-5-8-to-avoid-100-cpu-usage)

Comment: That looks like the right answer (and the link is splendid, BTW).  For some reason I cannot seem to be able to co-erce netbeans on windows to actually accept the param: -J-server even specifying an appropriate jdk and all. Anybody had any success with this?

Comment: @rogerpack: did you copy-paste the -J-server from this answer? Because sometime this can happen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169713/whats-the-toughest-bug-you-ever-found-and-fixed/170148#170148